# Axler's Measure Theory Section 6D #1 assistance

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I've proven $a \implies b \implies c$ very easily, but I can't figure out for the life of me $c \implies a$ (or any of the equivalent implicative routes). Any ideas? Here, $V'$ is the collection of all bounded linear functionals on $V$.

> Suppose that $V$ is a normed vector space and $\phi : V \longrightarrow \mathbb{F}$ is a linear functional on $V$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{F} \setminus \{0\}$.  Prove the following are equivalent:
>
> a) $\phi \in V'$.
>
> b) $\phi^{-1}(\{\alpha\})$ is closed in $V$.
>
> c) $\overline{\phi^{-1}(\{\alpha\}}) \neq V$.

Here's my best attempt at $c \implies a$ (i get rid of the case of $\phi = 0$ as its obvious)

Now suppose that c) is true.  Then $V \setminus \overline{\phi^{-1}(\{\alpha\})} \neq \emptyset$. Notice that by our assumption that $\phi \neq 0$ identically over $V$, we have that there exists $f \in V$ such that $\phi(f) \neq 0$. Thus it follows that $$\phi\left(\frac{\alpha f}{\phi(f)}\right) = \alpha \implies \phi^{-1}(\{\alpha\}) \neq \emptyset \implies \overline{\phi^{-1}(\{\alpha\})} \neq \emptyset.$$ Let $ V \setminus \overline{\phi^{-1}(\{\alpha\})} = A$ and $g \in A$. Then for $f \in \phi^{-1}(\{\alpha\}) \subset \overline{\phi^{-1}}(\{\alpha\})$, it follows that for $g \neq 2f$, we have that $\phi(g-f) \neq \phi(2f-f) = \alpha.$

Since $A$ is open, there exists $r > 0$ such that $$B_r(g-f) \subset A.$$ I claim that there exists sufficiently small $r > 0$ such that $B_r(g-f) \cap \text{Null} \: \phi = \emptyset$. Suppose for contradiction that this isn't true.  Then for all $r > 0$, there exists $h \in B_r(g-f) \cap \text{Null} \phi$.

Thus, it follows that $||(g-f)-h|| < r$. Equivalently, we have that $$||(g-h)-f|| < r \implies f \in B_r(g-h).$$ Notice that $\phi(g-h) = \phi(g) \neq \alpha$. Since $A$ is open, there exists sufficiently small $r_1 > 0$ such that $B_{r_1}(g-h) \subset A$.

However, since $f \in \phi^{-1}(\{\alpha\}) \subset \overline{\phi^{-1}(\{\alpha\})} = V \setminus A$, it follows that $f \notin B_{r_1}(g-h)$.  Therefore, we have that $$||(g-h)-f|| \geq r_1 \: \: \text{and} \: \: ||(g-h)-f|| < r.$$ Therefore, we have that $$r_1 \leq ||(g-h)-f|| < r \: \: \text{but} \: \: ||(g-h)-f|| = ||(g-f)-h|| \implies r_1 \leq ||(g-f)-h|| < r \implies h \notin B_{r_1}(g-f)$$ which is a contradiction, since we assumed that $h \in B_r(g-f)$ for all $r > 0$.  Thus, it must be the case that $$B_r(g-f) \cap \text{Null} \phi = \emptyset \: \: \text{for sufficiently small $r > 0$.}$$ Therefore, it follows that $\text{Null} \: \phi$ isn't dense in $V$, which implies that $\overline{\text{Null} \: \phi} \neq V$.  Thus $\phi \in V'$.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to show the contraposition, i.e. if $\phi$ is discontinuous, then those hyperplanes are dense.

Being discontinuous implies that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ exists $v_n\in V$ with $\Vert v\Vert =1$ and $\vert \phi(v_n)\vert >n$. Multiplying with a suitable phase and dividing by $\vert \phi(v_n)\vert$, we find $w_n\in V$ such that $\phi(w_n)=1$ and $\Vert w_n\Vert <1/n$.

Now let $x\in V$ and consider the the sequence
$$ x_n:=x+(\alpha-\phi(x))w_n.$$
Check that $x_n\in \phi^{-1}(\{\alpha\})$ and $x_n \rightarrow x.$ Hence, the closure of the hyperplane $ \phi^{-1}(\{\alpha\})$  is all of $V$.